# API EnumOutputs fails DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND on Win8/Windows 8

Tags: windows, directx, directx-11, directx-10

Was having an odd situation with our product being too bright on win8 compared to win7.  So tried PNTriangles11 DX SDK example and got the same results.  This was after testing the behavior at BestBuy and 24 systems all behaved the same way, all failed calling EnumOutputs.  It did not matter if desktop, laptop, all in one, or tablet.

[image: PNTriangles11 color problem]

Where our directx charting product looked like...  also shows our WPF charting component and even more variation in brightness caused by this same failure issue.

[image: DirectX charting component color problem, DirectX WPF Charting component]

So this led to researching and I find that I can reproduce on Win7 by adding below...

```
HRESULT CD3D11Enumeration::EnumerateOutputs( CD3D11EnumAdapterInfo* pAdapterInfo )
{
HRESULT hr;
IDXGIOutput* pOutput;

for( int iOutput = 0; ; ++iOutput )
{
    pOutput = NULL;
    hr = pAdapterInfo->m_pAdapter->EnumOutputs( iOutput, &pOutput );

// FORCE FAILURE ON WIN7 FOR TESTING PURPOSES
hr = DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND;

    if( DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND == hr )
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
    else if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        return hr;  //Something bad happened.
    }
    else //Success!
    {
        CD3D11EnumOutputInfo* pOutputInfo = new CD3D11EnumOutputInfo;
        if( !pOutputInfo
```

Though to get the sdk example to run now on Win8 and Win7 you also need to modify (adding the test for non zero hAdapterMonitor...

```
// Check to see if the window needs to be resized.  
// Handle cases where the window is minimized and maxmimized as well.

bool bNeedToResize = false;
if(hAdapterMonitor && DXUTGetIsWindowedFromDS( pNewDeviceSettings ) && 
!bKeepCurrentWindowSize )      
{
    UINT nClientWidth;
    UINT nClientHeight;
    if( IsIconic( DXUTGetHWNDDeviceWindowed() ) )
    {
```

The above allows you to tinker with the issue on win7 as a way to develop for win8.

So my question is, what is the best solution to handling EnumOutputs failing on Win8. And or what other changes to DXUT do you find useful.

Microsoft is working on this, and I will post their response, hopefully shortly, but a discussion of this topic is needed as so many dxut inspired software projects or those using EnumOutputs are failing on Win8.

ANSWER 1: Microsoft did get back to me with an initial response to get PNTriangles11 working on Win8.  They pointed me to the change within DXUTApplyDefaultDeviceSettings(DXUTDeviceSettings *modifySettings) where...

```
modifySettings->d3d11.sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
```

has to be changed to...

```
modifySettings->d3d11.sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
```

but the simple workaround for DXUTChangeDevice is still needed: a test for non zero hAdapterMonitor...

```
bool bNeedToResize = false;
if(hAdapterMonitor && DXUTGetIsWindowedFromDS( pNewDeviceSettings ) && !bKeepCurrentWindowSize ) 
{
    UINT nClientWidth;
    UINT nClientHeight;
    if( ::IsIconic( DXUTGetHWNDDeviceWindowed() ) )
    {
        // Window is currently minimized. To tell if it needs to resize,
```

Still waiting for an explanation from Microsoft why EnumOutputs failed on all 24 systems I tested at BestBuy.

Comment: Well, you seem to have found the problem and, with help and advice from Microsoft, you're converging on a solution. What is your question for us here?

Comment: Question still stands, how are developers handling EnunOutputs failing on Win8. Ignoring the api or features all together on Win8? Using an alternate api on Win8?  MS is still working on a formal answer as well. But hearing from others with direct experience of the issue would be ideal to get a variety of potential directions.

Comment: I'm having EnunOutputs fails for a while just after wake up the system and it starts working OK in a few seconds.